# ListBox Control Winforms Selected Item Color - Multiple List Box Controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have 5 list box controls on a single windows form. I'm setting the enabled property to false initially to control read/edit access. This makes it hard to read the selected value without enabling the control. I'm using the enabled property as the ListBox control doesn't have a read-only property like TextBox controls.

I've seen approaches online where I can set

```
ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
```

And use Draw_Item to control the select item colour.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, _  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) _
```

However, I've not seen an approach for applying this to multiple ListBox controls on a form. I don't really want to have to tap into Draw_Item for each ListBox.

Also, the ListBox controls are data bound to a DataSet. Anyone had this issue before? If so, how did you handle it?

Or does one know a way of controlling whether a ListBox control is read-only or selectable based on view/edit state?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: It appears that you're not looking for a solution for the "problem", but a solution for the solution you came up with to solve the "problem". There's a two-letters-name for this situation. Maybe, you could explain why you need to disable those controls in the first place.

Comment: Hi, sure, the reason to disable them is so users cannot change them until they explicitly put the controls into edit mode. With TextBox controls I can use .ReadOnly, but the only thing I have on a ListBox is Enabled.

Comment: ListBoxes are not editable, so this doesn't explain much. If, with `edit mode`, you mean you have some procedure that allows to insert/remove a ListBox's item(s), you should focus on that procedure. You can change the ForeColor of the Items in a disable ListBox(s), owner-drawing it, but is it really necessary? Doesn't it cause some confusion at some point? Can you manage it without causing collateral issues (e.g., Screen DPI changes, Font sizes, UI resizing)?

Comment: Thanks. I just don't want the user to be able to change the selected item in the listbox until they explicitly put the form into edit mode. Users can change the selected item if the control is enabled. Granted the change won't apply unless they hit the save button, but I didn't want them to be allowed to change the selected item in the listbox (by mistake) until they explicitly wanted to. I guess I'll have to live with not setting the enabled property to false and leave it enabled at all times. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Well, you could (just a suggestion) have a Boolean field (e.g.,  `IsEditMode`) that is set to false before editing is allowed. In the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler you could write something like: `If Not IsEditMode Then ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1  Return End If`. This can give a visual clue that an Item can't be selected and any other code in the handler won't be executed.

Comment: Thanks. I do this already. I guess I'm not too good at getting my message across :) The issue is more around the selected item not being readable when the ListBox control enabled property is set to false. I can tap into the draw_item method for each one to change the colour to make it more readable, but it seems long-winded. I think the ListBox just can't do what I'd like. I've left them as enabled for now, so at least the user can read what is selected in each one. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I don't see why @Jimi solution won't work. Nothing is selected. But, maybe an Extension method or a subclass of ListBox.

Comment: I think i know what you are trying to pass across, when the listbox is disabled, the items on it cannot be seen properly, You can change the listbox's forecolor to a brighter color before disabling it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I’ll play around with the forecolor to see if I can make them more readable. That would be a lot cleaner than providing a DrawItem for each one.